# How to validate a custom input using react-hook-form in Smart Form Component?

Tags: react-hook-form

I want to validate inputs using react-hook-form. but I couldn't send validations rules in register .how to resolve this

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-smart-form-component-vpsc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is already resolved at Github issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-smart-form-component-17k06

you can pass rules(validation) down as props

```
<Input name="firstName" rules={{ required: true }} />

export function Input({ register, name, rules, ...rest }) {
  return <input name={name} ref={register(rules)} {...rest} />;
}
```